# ASP .NET 5 - grunt task to copy files from node modules to wwwroot

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bower, asp.net-core, node-modules

I have a simple ASP .NET 5 empty project - with npm and grunt installed.

I've used npm to install a few client-side libraries, at present located in the node_modules directory directly under my ASP .NET project.

I want to copy the relevant files (for example, jquery.min.js) from the node_modules folder into the wwwroot folder.

It's unclear to me how to use grunt to do this - as each node module has it's own dependency tree, and there doesn't seem to be any consistency in the file structure from package to package.

I could write a grunt task explicitly for each client side library I use, but in that case I may as well download everything manually and place the files where I need them manually, avoiding npm all together.

I know I could use bower, which has a flat dependency tree - which is probably the root I should go down - but I've read a few articles saying "there's no need for bower - npm can do it all" and therefore I would like to know if there's a way to do this purely with npm.

Is there a way?  Or is the "npm can do it all" statement aimed at projects that will `require` the components directly from the node_modules?

**TL DR;** Is bower a better fit than npm for ASP .NET 5 projects with separation of source and build files, and if not, what's the recommended way of doing it purely with npm?

Comment: You didn't wrote any comments to my answer. Do you tried to use my suggestions? You wanted mostly to copy some files (for example, `jquery.min.js`) from the node_modules folder into the `wwwroot` folder. Can you do this now? If you want to get more information you should ask more questions. `grunt` or `gulp` allows you to have full control over the files placed in `wwwroot`, but one can still easy copy whole directories with files. If you have some opened questions, then it's better to ask there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oleg, and while it's a great explanation of how to use grunt, it doesn't answer my question. Writing a task or part of a task for each separate package I want to use is harder, more work, and more complex than downloading them and placing them manually.

Comment: What I want is 1 task that will copy the necessary files - including any new ones from packages that I get with npm after I've written the task.  I'm leaning towards using bower, or npm and requirejs.

Comment: You can copy whole `node_modules` to `wwwroot` with all subdirectories (you need use the corresponding options, remove `flatten: true`, `filter: "isFile"`, ..., see the options [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)), but it's **not recommended** way. Because you place in the way *anything* on your page. You can have both security problems (one can hack your site) and juristic problems (you can place illegal content and could have to pay for it). I would strictly control the content which you place on your web site.

Comment: I payed once 6000 EUR because somebody modified two jpg from somewhere and I just placed the two pictures on my web site without exact examination of origins of the pictures. I didn't know about it until I get the letter from a lawyer with the monetary claim. After the history I want to hold full control about all content of my web sites. You can trust every package which you find on npm, but, from juristic point of view, *you* will responsible for the content of your page and not node/npm of some unclear author, which you never seen.

Comment: I know, this is my point - I certainly don't want the entire node_modules copied over.  Only the minified js/css, and woff, etc.  Only the latest version too, npm doesn't seem like the right tool for the job contrary to a lot of posts I've read.  Bower it is.

Comment: If you want to copy *selected files*, then you should use the corresponding options of `grunt-contrib-copy`. Many CSS require gif, png, jpg and so on (see `images` folder of jQuery UI for example). Thus you still have to know about the content of packages which you distribute. Moreover I read in multiple sources that bower will be not developed more. It seems that npm will be the tool, which should be used.

Comment: If you use bower you have no control about the files included. Visual Studio just place all published content in `wwwroot\lib` by default. It's not the way which I would recommend to use.

Comment: By default yes, but you can change that - and then grunt-copy over what you want, and it's a flat dependency tree.

Comment: I think you understand already my opinion. Grunt have a lot of plugins and one can easy write copy task without any plugin. After the first start you can examine the options of `grunt-contrib-copy` and many other plugins and to choose the plugin and the option, which mostly corresponds to your personal preferences.

Answer (score 13):

I don't fill me professional in grunt, but I use it myself and I think that I can explain you how one can use it corresponds to your requirements.

First of all you should add "New Item" to your project, choose "Client-Side" and "NPM Configuration file" to add `package.json` to the the project (in the same directory where you have `project.json`). I suppose you have already created the file, but the existence of the file is important for grunt too. Then you adds some dependencies, which you need on the client-side to `"dependencies"` part of `package.json` and add at least `grunt` and `grunt-contrib-copy` to `"devDependencies"` part. An example of the file you will see below

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.2"
  }
}
```

Now you should add "Grunt Configuration File" in the same way like you added "NPM Configuration file". You will create `gruntfile.js` (in the same directory where you have `project.json`). Finally you should fill `gruntfile.js` with more helpful code. For example the code

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: ["wwwroot/font-awesome/", "wwwroot/jquery*.*"],
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: "node_modules/font-awesome/css/*",
                        dest: "wwwroot/font-awesome/css/",
                        expand: true,
                        filter: "isFile",
                        flatten: true
                    },
                    {
                        src: "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*",
                        dest: "wwwroot/font-awesome/fonts/",
                        expand: true,
                        filter: "isFile",
                        flatten: true
                    },
                    {
                        src: "node_modules/jquery/dist/*",
                        dest: "wwwroot/",
                        expand: true,
                        filter: "isFile",
                        flatten: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
    grunt.registerTask("all", ["clean", "copy"]);
    grunt.registerTask("default", "all");
};
```

registers two tasks: `clean` and `copy` and the aliases `all` and `default`. You can select `gruntfile.js` file in the solution explorer, open context menu and choose "Task Runner Explorer". You will see all defined tasks. The task with the name "default" will be executed if you execute `grunt` without parameters (without the task name) in the command line.

Now you can choose some task and run it. You can choose some task, click right mouse button to open context menu and check "After Build" in "Bindings":

[image]

Now the task will be executed every time when you build the project. You can click optionally "V" button on the left side to see verbose information from the executed tasks.

I hope it's already the main information which you need. Many other helpful information about plugins `grunt-contrib-clean`, `grunt-contrib-copy`, `grunt-contrib-jshint`, `grunt-jscs`, `grunt-newer` and many other you will find yourself. One official place of ASP.NET 5 documentation should be mentioned. It's [the place](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html).

P.S. You asked additionally about the usage of bower. I find both npm and bower not perfect, but still very practical. I would prefer to hold full control over the dependencies and especially about the data, which will be copied under `wwwroot`. Thus I change the content of `.bowerrc` file from `{ "directory": "wwwroot/lib" }` to `{ "directory": "bower_components" }` and I use grunt to copy the required data from `bower_components` in the same way like I do this with files from `node_modules`. See [the article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx) for more details. In other words I use packages published only in bower repository in the same way like I use npm packages.