# Is there a way to automatically copy files to wwwroot?

Tags: node.js, npm, asp.net-core

I have my *index.html* in the directory called *wwwroot* and it's being accessed from the browser on *locahost:5001*. Whe nI installed some packages using NPM, the directory *node_modules* was placed on the same level as *wwwroot*.

When I'm linking to the files, I use a relative path like this.

> href="../node_modules/package_this_or_that/package.min.js"

It seems to me that a better approach would be to have those delivered to the *wwwroot* directory and have them reside there. Not all the contents of the packages, just the files that are actually being used (skipping readmes etc.).

Is there a package for that? Or is it something that needs to be done using a build script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP .NET 5 - grunt task to copy files from node modules to wwwroot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455513/asp-net-5-grunt-task-to-copy-files-from-node-modules-to-wwwroot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This answer recommends using GULP [which seems dated now](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=%2Fg%2F11byyl8mbg).**

You are not supposed to access node_modules files from front-end like your html or cshtml files. So you are right you should copy them to the `wwwroot` folder.

You can use `grunt` as linked in [Tseng comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593122/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-copy-files-to-wwwroot#comment68421889_40593122) but I personally prefer `Gulp`, I think it's much quicker and easier to use.

Your `package.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-cached": "1.1.0",
    }
}
```

Then create a `gulpfile.js` at your project's root level and you can write something like

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
cache = require('gulp-cached'); //If cached version identical to current file then it doesn't pass it downstream so this file won't be copied 

gulp.task('default', 'copy-node_modules');

gulp.task('copy-node_modules', function () {

try {

    gulp.src('node_modules/**')
        .pipe(cache('node_modules'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/node_modules'));
    }
    catch (e) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Finally open the `Task Runner Explorer` (if you are using Visual Studio) and execute either your `default` task or directly the `copy-node_modules` task.

Gulp is very useful, I suggest you explore other different gulp tasks. You can concat and minify both CSS and JS files, remove comments, you can even create a `watch` task that executes other tasks as soon as a file changes.

Comment: As long as my hunches seems to be accurate, I have another question, related to the copy process. In your example, you simply copy over all CSS and JS files. However, I noticed that the structure of the packages looks like compilable projects themselves. Should I, perhaps, rather execute them somehow using Gulp fetching **only the relevant** but **all the relevant** artifacts? I'm thinking that some packages might contain fonts, images etc. (which isn't covered by your example) and that only minified files need to be copied. There's a directory called *dist*, for instance...

Comment: Yes of course you can copy all the `node_modules` folder I think it would be something like `gulp.src('node_modules/')` but you should create your own rules instead. For example some modules have `test` or `examples` folders so you don't need that in your wwwroot. For my example I just took my own gulp file and modified it to give you an example. (I manually copied the only module I needed to wwwroot which reminds me I should actually change that and automate it like you...). `dist` contains the production version with minified files but not all modules have it

Comment: I updated the code sample of the answer. This will copy everything to your wwwroot. I'm not super advanced with this, I just learnt the basis not long ago, but honestly I think you don't need everything, don't pollute your wwwroot with useless things. I think you should only copy the modules you actually use. (be prepared for maybe a Visual Studio crash the first time you copy everything)